# Is it possible to determine the compiler / linker options used to generate a binary (exe, dll)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, compiler-optimization

Assume the following situation: you have either a **DLL** or an **executable file**, all you know is that this is the binary result created by a specific Visual Studio Version (i.e. VS 2017) using C++.

Question: Is there any way to tell from only this binary file which **compiler options** (i.e. Optimizations,  Runtime Library, etc.), and/or **linker options** (Additional Dependencies, etc.) were used to compile and link this file?

Which kind of this "meta information" is actually present in the final binary file (exe, dll), and which tools are available to get this kind of information?

Comment: Source code isn't available, is it?

Comment: Dumpbin will tell you quite a lot - not sure about optimisation level though